# How to simplify jQuery in navbar functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dirty, hacked couple of jQuery functions for my navbar that I need help cleaning up.

Basically, I have a simple toolbar that changes color after the user scrolls to a certain point on the page (as the background of the page is white, the menu items change to black, and the background of the bar from transparent to white).

However, when an overlay toggle in the menu is clicked, the client wants the overlay to be black and the items to become white. I've achieved this with a nasty but my jQuery skills are still very premature...

Change color after scrolling to a certain point:

```
var scroll_start = 0;
var startchange = $('.nav-null');
var Heightofit = startchange.outerHeight()-100;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    scroll_start = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (scroll_start > Heightofit) {
        $('nav.global_nav').css('background-color', 'rgba(255,255,255,1)');
        $('nav.global_nav i').css('color', 'rgba(0,0,0,0.9)');
        $('.logo svg g').css('fill', 'rgba(0,0,0,0.9)');
        $('#trigger-overlay span').css('background-color', 'rgba(0,0,0,0.9)');
    } else {
        $('nav.global_nav').css('background-color', 'transparent');
        $('nav.global_nav i').css('color', 'rgba(255,255,255,1)');
        $('.logo svg g').css('fill', 'rgba(255,255,255,1)');
        $('#trigger-overlay span').css('background-color', 'rgba(255,255,255,1)');
    }
});
```

Flip colors when toggle is clicked:

```
$('#hamburger').toggle(function () {
    $("#hamburger span, nav, nav.global_nav i").addClass("flip");
    $('.logo svg g').css('fill', 'rgba(255,255,255,1)');
}, function () {
    $("#hamburger span, nav, nav.global_nav i").removeClass("flip");
    $('.logo svg g').css('fill', 'rgba(0,0,0,0.9)');
    return false;
});
```

I'd appreciate any insight into how best to combine and/or clean up this mess.

Comment: Can you please html and css

Comment: It doesn't look all that messy to me. And since there's no obvious "correct" answer, e.g. it's already working, and "cleaner" is subjective, this question probably belongs in code review.

Comment: You're updating different attributes of different elements. Besides some chaining, which wouldn't clear up much, I'm not sure things should change.

Answer (score 1):

This is the best I could come up with.

```
<style>
  nav.global_nav { background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1); }
  nav.global_nav.alt { background-color: transparent; }

  nav.global_nav i { color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); }
  nav.global_nav i.alt { color: rgba(255,255,255,1); }

  .logo svg g { fill: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); }
  .logo svg g.alt { fill: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); }

  #trigger-overlay span { background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); }
  #trigger-overlay span.alt { background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1); }
</style>

<script>
  ...
  var elems = $('nav.global_nav, nav.global_nav i, .logo svg g, #trigger-overlay span');
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    scroll_start = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (scroll_start > Heightofit) {
      elems.addClass('alt');
    } else {
      elems.removeClass('alt');
    }
  }
  ...
  var elems2 = $("#hamburger span, nav, nav.global_nav i");
  var logoElem = $('.logo svg g');
  $('#hamburger').toggle(function () {
    elems2.addClass('flip');
    logoElem.addClass('alt');
  }, function () {
    elems2.removeClass('flip');
    logoElem.removeClass('alt');
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

All looks good to me, although, if you are altering the CSS programmatically like this, I might be inclined to have your regularly used css properties set as constants...

```
const COLOUR_WHITE = 'rgba(255,255,255,1)';
const COLOUR_BLACK = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.9)';

var scroll_start = 0;
var startchange = $('.nav-null');
var Heightofit = startchange.outerHeight()-100;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    scroll_start = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (scroll_start > Heightofit) {
        $('nav.global_nav').css('background-color', BG_COLOUR);
        $('nav.global_nav i').css('color', COLOUR_BLACK);
        $('.logo svg g').css('fill', COLOUR_BLACK);
        $('#trigger-overlay span').css('background-color', COLOUR_BLACK);
    } else {
        $('nav.global_nav').css('background-color', 'transparent');
        $('nav.global_nav i').css('color', COLOUR_WHITE);
        $('.logo svg g').css('fill', COLOUR_WHITE);
        $('#trigger-overlay span').css('background-color', COLOUR_WHITE);
    }
});

$('#hamburger').toggle(function () {
    $("#hamburger span, nav, nav.global_nav i").addClass("flip");
    $('.logo svg g').css('fill', COLOUR_WHITE);
}, function () {
    $("#hamburger span, nav, nav.global_nav i").removeClass("flip");
    $('.logo svg g').css('fill', COLOUR_BLACK);
    return false;
});
```

This way, you can change the "theme" in one place

Comment: Apologies, that was overly sarcastic. I'll delete my first comment. You could do this using CSS selectors and then simply toggle a class on the parent containing element, similar to what jkris has done in his answer. It tidies up the code because you just need the single line to add/remove the class, means you don't have random bits of styling declared in your JavaScript, and makes it easier to re-use those styles on elements that aren't interacted with in any way by your code.

Comment: Thanks, guys. I dig the first one b/c it doesn't rely as heavily on jQuery, but I didn't know about the jQuery const attribute — that's a valuable lesson. I'll try them both out.

Comment: btw there's an example of what i'm going for at hugeinc.com